# API to get User progress data from D2L class

Tags: desire2learn

I am looking for way to get the user progress data from D2L, is there any API available for getting the user progress data for a class?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the Valence Learning Framework APIs don't provide access to user progress functionality. Desire2Learn does maintain a [Product Idea Exchange](https://community.desire2learn.com/d2l/lp/navbars/1796/customlinks/external/15394) through which D2L clients (and interested stakeholders) can provide use-cases and requests for platform enhancement: you can register your interest there, or through your account or partner manager.